# Different label and hint for TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to make a `EditTextLayout`, but I want a different text for label and hint.

For example :  The label's text is "Phone Number", and the hint text is 
"+6281342134".

Is it possible?

My code is:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="+6281342134"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: `android:label="Phone Number"
android:hint="+6281342134"`

Comment: I tried to add on focus listener and change the hint when the edittext got focus. It works, but i don't think it is the best solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use these attribute:

- **`android:hint`**: for the label
- **`placeholderText`**: for the placeholder text inside the `EditText`

  ```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            app:placeholderText="+6281342134"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="+6281342134"
                android:inputType="phone" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
  ```

[image]

If the placeholder should be displayed also when the text field is empty just add the **expandedHintEnabled="false"**:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
```

[image]

**Note:** the `expandedHintEnabled` requires at least the version `1.3.0-alpha03`.

Comment: This implements the requirements of the question using the latest enhancements of 1.3.0. The other solutions were workarounds using the older 1.2.0 library, hence this should now be flagged as the correct answer.

Answer (score 52):

I took a similar approach to Rehan

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            inputLayout.setHint("We did it!");
        } else {
            inputLayout.setHint("Testing 123");
        }
    }
});
```

The animation was good enough for me without disabling the animation:

[image: Example]

Comment: you can compress the if statement, by using a command as follows: `inputLayout.setHint(hasFocus ? "We did it!" : "Testing 123");`

Answer (score 29):

Here's how I'm doing it without code (just XML), while allowing both a label and a placeholder at the same time, as in the Material Design guidelines.

Layout XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="My Label Text">
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@android:id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@drawable/hint_selector"
    android:hint="Placeholder Text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Color Selector XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="?android:textColorHint" />
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The key here is to just make it transparent by default, and only show the placeholder text when it has focus. No need to change color either, since this will respect any custom theme in place, as well as light and dark themes.

Comment: ?android:textColorHint requires min API level 21

Comment: @JohnnyFive You can easily replace it with any color you want, or use the appcompat support library.

Comment: It's a good solution but when the user changes the focus to another EditText then the label text disappears. It's a little "ugly" when you are filling a form with several EditText. Is there a selector state to resolve this "problem"? Thank you.

Comment: @Alex, make sure you're using `android:hint` in both TextInputLayout (the label text) and in TextInputEditText (the placeholder text). Perhaps you didn't add one to TextInputLayout.

Comment: This answer works better than the others because the other solution of using the `OnFocusChangeListener` requires a double tap of the EditText to show the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do it by this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Phone Number">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="+6281342134"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But this will result overlapping of both hints i.e. *Phone Number* and *+6281342134*. So you need to implement `OnFocusChangeListener` for this. (Not so good solution but it'll work for you).

In your layout, add hint to `TextInputLayout` only. I have set `hintAnimationEnabled` to `false` because I think the animation might won't look smooth with different hints.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Phone Number"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In your java file, create `OnFocusChangeListener`:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener onPhoneNumberFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            ((EditText)v).setHint("+6281342134");
        } else {
            ((EditText)v).setHint("");
        }
    }
};
```

and set it to your `EditText`

```
phone.setOnFocusChangeListener(onPhoneNumberFocusChangeListener);
```

Comment: I think we need to stop putting the word 'simply' in Android-related answers.

Comment: Is it possible without **TextInputLayout**?
Actually i already set hint programmatically and it's working good.
but now i want set text same way and issue was occur hint goes hide after setting the text

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the floating label using `android:hint="@string/EMAIL"`. So for the hint inside the box, I used `app:placeholderText="e.g. someone@mailbox.com"`.

To have a floating action button enabled all the time you have to use `requestFocus()`.

Answer (score -4):

Go into the xml text editting mode and add this to the edittext:

```
android:label="Phone Number"
android:hint="+6281342134"
```